# Python - insert multiples rows into an existing data frame

Tags: python

I am trying to insert two lines into an existing data frame, but can't seem to get it to work. The existing df is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3,4,5,6], "block" : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]})
```

I want to add two blank rows after the 1st and 2nd block rows. I would like the new data frame to look like this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6], "block" : [1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3]})
```

There doesn't need to be any values in the rows, I'm planning on using them as placeholders for something else. I've looked into adding rows, but most posts suggest appending one row to the beginning or end of a data frame, which won't work in my case.

Any suggestions as to my dilemma?

Comment: Is there a logic for that specific spot to go off of? I'm assuming it's based on the repetition in `block` column.

Comment: Yes, I want to have these inserted rows come right after the end of each block section in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Adds a new row to a DataFrame
# oldDf   - The DataFrame to which the row will be added
# index   - The index where the row will be added
# rowData - The new data to be added to the row
# returns - A new DataFrame with the row added
def AddRow(oldDf, index, rowData):
    newDf = oldDf.head(index)
    newDf = newDf.append(pd.DataFrame(rowData))
    newDf = newDf.append(oldDf.tail(-index))

    # Clean up the row indexes so there aren't any doubles.
    # Figured you may want this.
    newDf = newDf.reset_index(drop=True)

    return newDf

# Initial data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3,4,5,6], "block" : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]})

# Insert rows
blankRow = {"a": [0], "block": [0]}
df2 = AddRow(df1, 2, blankRow)
df2 = AddRow(df2, 5, blankRow)
```

For the sake of performance, you can removed the reference to Reset_Index() found in the AddRow() function, and simply call it after you've added all your rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to insert the new row of zeros after each group of values in the `block` column you can do the following:

Start with your data frame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3,4,5,6], "block" : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]})
```

Group it using the values in the `block` column:

```
gr = df1.groupby('block')
```

Add a row of zeros to the end of each group:

```
df_new = gr.apply(lambda x: x.append({'a':0,'block':0}, ignore_index=True))
```

Reset the indexes of the new dataframe:

```
df_new.reset_index(drop = True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) the data based on the `block` column, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the placeholder at the bottom of each group then [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to a new dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3,4,5,6], "block" : [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]})

df1 # original data
Out[67]: 
   a  block
0  1      1
1  2      1
2  3      2
3  4      2
4  5      3
5  6      3

df_group = df1.groupby('block')

df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [], "block" : []}) # final data to be appended

for name,group in df_group:
    group = pd.concat([group,pd.DataFrame({"a" : [0], "block" : [0]})])
    df = df.append(group, ignore_index=True)


df
Out[71]: 
   a  block
0  1      1
1  2      1
2  0      0
3  3      2
4  4      2
5  0      0
6  5      3
7  6      3
8  0      0
```